# Uploading large files to aws s3 bucket without loading to memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload 2GB+ file to my bucket using `MultipartFile` and `AmazonS3`, controller:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public String uploadFile(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    String fileUploadResult =  this.amazonClient.uploadFile(file);
    return fileUploadResult;
}
```

amazonClient-uploadFile:

```
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder fileUrl = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
        String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
        fileUrl.append(endpointUrl);
        fileUrl.append("/");
        fileUrl.append(bucketName);
        fileUrl.append("/");
        fileUrl.append(fileName);
        uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName, file);
        file.delete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return fileUrl.toString();
}
```

amazonClient-convertMultiPartToFile:

```
private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }
```

amazonClient-uploadFileTos3bucket:

```
private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
    s3client.putObject(
            new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
}
```

The process works well for small file, to deal with large ones I defined in my application.properties -

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5GB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=5GB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

And getting - `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` so:

1- How can I upload file without loading it to memory(not sure that is possible)?

2- How to load it in smaller parts?

Excption -

```
{"timestamp":"2018-11-12T12:50:38.250+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"No message available","trace":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError\r\n\tat java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)\r\n\tat java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)\r\n\tat java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)\r\n\tat java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)\r\n\tat org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:143)\r\n\tat org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:110)\r\n\tat org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(FileCopyUtils.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getBytes(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:245)\r\n\tat com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.handels.AmazonClient.convertMultiPartToFile(AmazonClient.java:51)\r\n\tat com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.handels.AmazonClient.uploadFile(AmazonClient.java:75)\r\n\tat com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.controllers.BucketController.uploadFile(BucketController.java:48)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n","path":"/storage/uploadFile"}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `low level API`.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Comment: It stil loads the file to the memory - `File file = new File(filePath);`.

Comment: I do not think the file contents loaded to memory by instantiating the `File` Object. Does it?

Comment: Related: https://www.novixys.com/blog/java-reading-large-file-efficiently/#3_Loading_a_Binary_File_in_Chunks and https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: @AmidalaSivaKumar - no but I found out the root cause - `file.getBytes()`

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem and I solved it by directly uploading the file as stream to the bucket.

In case you are using `java servlet` , below line of code is to read the `video` from `form-data`.

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("video");
//Now convert it to inputstream
InputStream in = request.getPart("video").getInputStream();
```

Now I made one `S3Class`, below is the part of code from the function.

```
try {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                .build();

        ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
        meta.setContentLength(in.available());
        meta.setContentType("video/mp4");


        TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
                .withS3Client(s3Client)
                .build();


        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, in, meta);
        Upload upload = tm.upload(request);

        // Optionally, you can wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
        upload.waitForCompletion();
        if(upload.isDone())
        {
                System.out.println("Total bytes transferred is : "+totalBytesTransferred);
                tm.shutdownNow();
        }
   } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
        // it, so it returned an error response.
        output = "Couldn't Upload the file.";
        output_code = 0;
        System.out.println("Inside exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SdkClientException e) {
        // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client 
        // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
        output = "Couldn't Upload the file.";
        output_code = 0;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**P.S.** Don't forget to add `setContentLength()` to `ObjectMetaData` else it will lead to OOM error.